# React: Close a modal clicking outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a **modal** reaction component with a button that opens the modal. The modal also has a close button. Here is the code and what the modal looks like:

```js
class Modal extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        title: "Modal Title",
        float: false,
        color: "pink",
        children: <div>Add children here!</div>
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            show: false
        }
    }

    openModal() {
        this.setState(
            { show: true }
        )
    }

    closeModal() {
        this.setState(
            { show: false }
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className={"modal-button" + " " + this.props.color} onClick={() => this.openModal()}>{this.props.title}</button>
                {this.state.show && <div className={"modal fade-in" + " " + (this.props.float ? "modal-float" : null)}>
                    <div className="modal-head">
                        <span>{this.props.title}</span>
                        <button id='button' onClick={() => this.closeModal()}>x</button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-body">
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                </div>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[image: It has a button that opens the modal. And the modal has a close button too.]

I would like close the modal clicking outside. In another question I saw a code like this

```js
handleClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ showModal: true }, () => {
      document.addEventListener("click", this.closeMenu);
    });
  };

closeMenu = () => {
    this.setState({ menuOpen: false }, () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
    });
  }
```

But it also close the modal when I click inside the modal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a condition that doesn't close the modal when the modal is open and a click originates inside the modal. To detect where a click is happening, you will probably use refs.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

For ex, I added this condition in the closeMenu function:

```
this.modalRef = React.createRef();

handleClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ showModal: true }, () => {
      document.addEventListener("click", this.closeMenu);
    });
  };

closeMenu = () => {
  if(this.modalRef.current && this.modalRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
    return; 
}
    this.setState({ menuOpen: false }, () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
    });
  }


render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.modalRef}>
       // modal component 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This detects 1. if the modal is open (`this.modalRef.current`) and 2. if the click originates inside the modal (`this.modalRef.current.contains(event.target)`), in which case it returns and does not close the modal.

This explains the approach, although it uses hooks not class components, the concept is the same: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/detect-a-click-outside-of-a-react-component-with-a-reusable-hook-and-useref-a0c282171c3f